# Unknown provider error in jasmine test case

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to angular. I am not getting what's wrong with the following code. I have gone through this link [ http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=scrollToAttachmentsProvider%20%3C-%20scrollToAttachments ] and unable to find my case there

```
beforeEach(module('my_app'));


var initiate_controller = function(){
inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  spyOn(window, 'hide_page_loader');
  $controller('EntryShowController', {
    $scope: $scope,
    $state: $state,
    entryData: entryData,
    entryHistory: entryHistory
  });
  $scope.$digest();
});
```

};

Comment: is that your complete code?

Comment: no except this code entryData, entryHistory, scope and state are defined

Comment: scrollToAttachments where does it come from

Comment: it's defined in the controller but not in the test case

Comment: I have defined scrollToAttachments in controller and now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error , you have not defined **`scrollToAttachments`**  anywhere in the code,

Add it to the controller.

```
 $controller('EntryShowController', {
    $scope: $scope,
    $state: $state,
    entryData: entryData,
    entryHistory: entryHistory
  });
```